# Moved an internal website, now need to un-break URL bookmarks

Tags: iis-6, redirect, website, virtual-directory

Got a client who has a website accessed over the local area network (emphasis, not over the internet).  The previous version of the website was installed incorrectly as a virtual directory under the default website.  So, everyone was used to going to the following address:

http://example/MyWebApp

After installing a major update, the server was configured correctly and the web application was set up as the default on the server.

http://example/

Of course, everybody is now complaining that their URLs don't work anymore.  How can I configure IIS6 to un-break their bookmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinoud's solution is probably the quickest fix (a bit "low-tech" but it works).

http://www.highposition.net/301-redirect-tutorial-iis/ (or any of a number of other sites Google returns for "IIS 301 redirect") has information on setting up 301/302 redirects for the "HTTP-clean" implementation, complete with screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way would be to create a directory called MyWebApp on the new location containing an index.html file with the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://example/" />
```

Comment: I was hoping for more of a 301 type redirect....

Comment: ... Or configure IIS to do a HTTP/301 ("Moved Permanently") Redirect.

Comment: Ah, since you where explicitly refering to a lan web application I assumed there was no real need for a 301, as http 301 type redirects are mostly used for SEO purposes.

Comment: Well, that's the thing; I'm not exactly sure what's the best choice.  I'd prefer a less... hacky... way of doing this.  A redirect (301 or otherwise, SEO be damned) seems a better route.